# Probability inequality with EX

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $\xi$ have finite mathematical expectation and $g(x)$ be a concave function.Prove that $E(g(\xi)) \le g(E(\xi))$.

The problem seems difficult to me, it is the first time I face probability inequalities.

Comment: Do you know the Jensen Inequality?

Comment: You have sated the inequality wrongly. Instead of $\geq $ what you get is $\leq$.

Answer (score 1):

What you seek is [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). Let me give a short proof assuming that the function $g$ is differentiable at the point $E(\xi)$ (Otherwise, we need the notion of [subdifferential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) to make the proof general.)

Let $a = E(\xi)$. Since $g$ is a concave function, for all $y\in \mathcal{C}$ (where $\mathcal{C}$ is the domain of $g$) we have that $$g(y)\le g(a)+(y-a)g'(a)\ \ (\mbox{Prove this!}).$$  Therefore, $$g(\xi)\le g(a)+(\xi-a)g'(a)\implies E(g(\xi))\le g(a)+(E\xi-a)g'(a)\\\implies Eg(\xi)\le g(E\xi),$$where the last step follows from the observation that $E\xi=a$.